# Can hexadecimal numbers be added/subtracted with decimal numbers?

Tags: c, binary, hex, decimal

When programming in C, say if I have integer h as a hexadecimal value and integer d as a decimal number. Can I do addition or subtraction between h and d? Or do they have have to be in the same number system?

Comment: Give it a shot and see!  http://ideone.com/ is an online compiler that you can use without installing anything to run little test programs like this.

Comment: I think this question also confuses "numbers" and "values".  0x12, 0d18, 0o22, and 0b00010010 are all "numbers" that represent the same "value".  When you add, you add values - not numbers.

Comment: You are confused between "number" and "representation".  Internally, a computer has "numbers".  Externally (what you see and type) there are "representations".  Decimal is a representation.  Hex is a representation.  Even "Q" is a representation.  If you enter a hex representation and a decimal representation (and somehow tell the computer which is which) they both get converted to "numbers" internally which you can add or subtract or whatever, without worrying about whether the representation used to enter the number was hex or decimal.

Comment: @HotLicks - Five seconds too slow! :p +1 anyway

Comment: (Or course, Pete has used "numbers" and "values" instead of "representations" and "numbers", but this merely illustrates that the terminology is not very rigidly defined.  But the distinction is there no matter what you call them.)

Comment: Which compiler supports `0d18` and `0o22`?  C++14 compilers (and MS and GNU as non-standard extensions) support `0b00010010`.  C++14 goes further and allows `0b0001'0000` with the single quote being an (optional) grouping marker (which can be used with all number bases).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can write:

```
int x = 100 - 0x100 + 0100;
```

That mixes decimal with hex and octal.  The values are all converted to binary anyway before the calculation occurs (and the compiler will do the calculation in this example; it won't be evaluated at runtime).  And any of the constants can be replaced by an `int` value that was assigned the appropriate value:

```
int d = 100;
int h = 0x100;
int o = 0100;
int x = d + h + o;
```

Comment: Like the base 10, 16, 8 trio.

Comment: why if add 1 to int `num`  with hex value `0x7fffffff` I get `-2147483648` , if I changed it to `long` I get right number `2147483648 ` ?

Comment: @Zizoo: Nominally, that's a new question that could be asked/answered separately. If you're working on a machine where `sizeof(int) == 4 && sizeof(long) == 8` (a 64-bit Unix system, for example; not Windows 64, though), then that's what would be expected, more or less. Officially, adding 1 to 0x7FFFFFFF when the value is an `int` leads to undefined behaviour as it wraps past (2^31)-1; commonly, it changes to 0x80000000, which is the hexadecimal representation of the most negative 32-bit signed integer (on 2's complement machines). _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ When you change to a 64-bit type (`long`, or `long long`, etc), then adding 1 yields 0x80000000, but that's well within the normal range of values and gives you the positive number when printed as a decimal.

Answer (score 0):

Yes they can, for example

```
int x;
x = 0x0F + 10;
printf("%d\n", x);
```

Output:

```
25
```

the representation you use doesn't matter, it will be ultimately all converted to binary after all.