# AVR C hex and dec multiplication not as expected

Tags: c, embedded, avr

I just discovered a bug in my code when multiplying hex integers (ex. 0xFFFF) with dec integers (ex. 2). This is the code where the problem occurs:

```
print_int_new_line(0xFFFF*2);
print_int_new_line(65535*2);
```

Executing this code gives me the following result:

```
65534
131070
```

This is relevant UART code:

```
void print_int_new_line(uint64_t data) {
    print_int(data);

    print_new_line();
}

void print_int(uint64_t data) {
    char data_buffer[(int)(log(data)+2)]; // size of the number (log(number)+1) + 1 for the /0

    ultoa(data, data_buffer, 10); // convert the int to string, base 10

    // print the newly created string
    print_string(data_buffer);
}

void print_string(char * data) {

    // transmit the data char by char
    for(; *data != '\0'; data++){
        USART_transmit(data);
    }
}

void USART_transmit(const char * data){
    /* Wait for empty transmit buffer */
    while ( !( UCSR0A & (1<<UDRE0)) )
    ;

    /* Put data into buffer, sends the data */
    UDR0 = *data;
}
```

Some info about my setup:

MCU: ATmega2560
Board: Arduino Mega2560
UART baudrate: 38400
IDE: Atmel Studio 7.0.4.1417

Using the AVR toolchain.

I read on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28445459/can-hexadecimal-numbers-be-added-subtracted-with-decimal-numbers) stackoverflow page that multiplication is possible between hex and dec ints. Also, testing this in an [online](https://www.onlinegdb.com/online_c_compiler) c compiler gives the correct output.

Can anyone give me an explanation?

Comment: Have you tried casting 0xFFFF to 32-bit int?  It almost seems as if compiler is treating 0xFFFF as 16-bit int.

Comment: `log` is a *natural* logarithm. Not speaking of the peculiarity of the whole method...

Comment: What is the size of an `int` on this platform (AVR toolchain), and for a `long` ? Is it really a 8 bits CPU ? You should try to append `uL` at the end of the constant

Comment: @benjarobin ATmega2560 is an 8-bit processor.

Comment: @benjarobin : Yest it really is an 8 bit processor.  Why does that surprise you?  It is tagged embedded - a domain where 8 bit devices remain fairly common,

Comment: There are no hex and dec `int`s, they are all just `int`s.  The representation in the source code is just a human readable representation in different forms to suit different purposes.  The compiler generates the appropriate binary integers when it translates the source.  However while 0xFFFF is translated to an `unsigned int` and 65534 is a `signed int`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This behavior is due to differences in handling decimal and hexadecimal integer constants.

For both `0xFFFF` and `65535`, the compiler will first try to convert the value to an `int`. But since the platform has a 16-bit `int` type where `INT_MAX` is `32767`, that conversion cannot be performed.

The key difference is the next step. For the hexadecimal constant `0xFFFF`, the compiler will try to convert it to an `unsigned int`, which it does to the equivalent of `(unsigned int)65535`. But, for the decimal constants, conversions to unsigned types are not attempted. The next conversion attempt is to `long int`. This succeeds and is equivalent to `(long int)65535`.

So the calls to `print_int_new_line` are equivalent to:

```
print_int_new_line((unsigned int)65535*2);
print_int_new_line((long int)65535*2);
```

And when `2` is promoted to do the multiplication:

```
print_int_new_line((unsigned int)65535*(unsigned int)2);
print_int_new_line((long int)65535*(long int)2);
```

The `unsigned int` result of the first multiplication is too small to hold the full result, so it is truncated to `65534`. The `long int` can hold the result, so it produces the correct answer of `131070`.

You can force the hexadecimal constant to use a `long int` by appending an `L` (i.e. `0xFFFFL`).

Comment: Nice answer.  However given the data type of the `print_int_new_line()` argument, casting to `uint64_t` might be more appropriate for complete type agreement and to avoid possible further type promotion issues for other larger values.

Comment: Casts are a really bad idea. If you want a specific minimum width, use the `stdint.h` macros for constants, e.g. `UINT64_C`. To get unsigned types, append the `unsigned` marker to the constant, i.e. `65535U`, etc. That still leaves speculations what OP actually expected.